Can I see the logs when Webots crashes?
Wondering if there's something built-in already to show me the error/crash report when Webots crashes unexpectedly?
I'm getting intermittent crashes when interacting with custom protos in the scene tree, and I can't find any info about the crashes anywhere. Hoping I'm just missing something simple.
(To clarify since someone will probably ask - I'm talking about crashes of the actual Webots application, not any robot controllers. There is no simulation running when these crashes occur.)

You can use the --log-performance and --sysinfo option to save the system logs into a log file as described in here:
https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/starting-webots?version=cyberbotics:R2019a

I just tried this - it seems as though --log-performance only does anything if I run the simulation (it logs performance of the sim not the actual application), and --sysinfo doesn't give any info when it crashes. Any suggestions?
